# Can we load only specific variants of a font family using webfontloader?

Tags: reactjs, webfonts, google-font-api, google-webfonts, google-fonts

**Context:** I have started out to eliminate the render blocking nature of fonts as browser behaviour, did some research and found out using [webfontloader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader), we can load them asynchronously.

**Problem:** I have to load only specific(400,500,500i) variants of Roboto, using [webfontloader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader), asynchronously

**Method:** I tried to solve with the below snippet:

```
class MyPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <RootPage {...this.props}/>
  }
}

const options = {
  google: {
    families: ['Roboto:400,500,500i']
  }
}
export default WithWebFontLoaderHOC({ options })(MyPage)
```

**ExpectedOutput:** The snippet should load only three specified variants of Roboto.

**RealOutput:** It is loading all twelve variants of Roboto.

**NOTE**: I have not referenced anywhere in the codebase

> font family: Roboto;

*So is this the right way to go? or whats the missing piece?*

**ExtraInfo:**

```
const WithWebFontLoaderHOC = ({ options }) => (WrappedComponent: any) => {
  class RenderComponent extends Component<WithWebFontLoaderHOCProps> {
    componentDidMount() {
      // This will make sure WebFont.load is only used in the browser.
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        const WebFont = require('webfontloader') //eslint-disable-line
        WebFont.load(options)
      }
    }
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }
  RenderComponent.displayName = `WithWebFontLoaderHOC(${WrappedComponent.displayName ||
    WrappedComponent.name})`
  return RenderComponent
}
```